# set hive.cli.print.current.db and hive.cli.print.header not working

Tags: hadoop, hive

I have tried all suggested changes in other replies like creating a find **.hiverc** in **/etc/hive/conf** with **set hive.cli.print.current.db=true;** and **set hive.cli.print.header=true;**. It did not work.

I tried the same in /etc/hive/conf. That also did not work.

FYI I am using a cloudera training environment.

Thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using hive in remote mode (clidriver connecting to hiveserver), these options probably won't work.

You can try using cli in local mode, or beeline + hiverserver2.

Comment: This worked.. Thanks for your help.. any documentation available for this?

Comment: I didn't learn this from doc. I debugged hive a lot so I know. Sorry :(